# not able to edit currently logged-in user profile in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to edit currently logged-in user profile. I have used Spring Security Service plugin for user management. User ( which is subscriber in my application) contains field which come from different domain like:

**1. User(subscriber in app): has username, password.
 2  Profile:has emailaddress and phonenumber etc. 
 3. Person:has Firstname and lastname.**

All above domains make a complete profile for user(subscriber).

Now I want to edit currently logged-in user profile like firstname, lastname or email.
I tried with following code.

```
def userSettings = {
    Subscriber loggedinSubscriber = Subscriber.get( springSecurityService.principal.id )
    if (loggedinSubscriber){
    Profile profile = Profile?.get(params.id);
    Party person = profile?.Person?.get(params.id);
    if (!person){
      flash.message = "could not find user with ${params.id}"
      redirect action: list
    }
    else
    [person: person, authorityList: sortedRoles()]
    }
    else {
      redirect(controller: "login" , action:"login");
    }
  }
```

But it did not work. Here I got currently logged in user id but profile is null.

**Profile domain:**

```
package com.vproc.member

import java.util.Date;

import com.vproc.enquiry.Enquiry;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Membership;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Team;

    class Profile {

        String emailAddress  //  field governed by privacy policy
        String phoneNumber   //  field governed by privacy policy
        Date dateCreated
        Date lastUpdated
        boolean isDefaultProfile
        static belongsTo = [ Person]
        //ProfilePrivacyLevelEnum privacyLevel = ProfilePrivacyLevelEnum.Private

        static constraints = {
        }
    }
```

**Person domain:**

package com.vproc.member

```
import com.vproc.enquiry.Enquiry;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Membership;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Notification;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Team;

class Person extends Party{

    String firstName
    String lastName

    Profile profile
    static belongsTo = [Organization]

    static constraints = {
        lastName nullable:true
        firstName blank:false

    }

}
```

**Subscriber domain:**
package com.vproc.member

import java.util.Date;

import com.vproc.common.StatusEnum;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Discussion;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Enquiry;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Membership;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Notification;
import com.vproc.enquiry.SharedEnquiry;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Team;
import com.vproc.order.Seat;

```
class Subscriber extends PartyRole{

  transient springSecurityService

  String username
  String password
  boolean enabled
  boolean accountExpired
  boolean accountLocked
  boolean passwordExpired
  StatusEnum status
  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated
  List<Contact> contacts ;

  static belongsTo = [ customer: Customer]
  static hasMany = [seats: Seat, ownedEnquiries: Enquiry,enquiresSharedWith: SharedEnquiry,]


  static constraints = {
  //  username  validator : { val , obj ->
              //   if (obj.status != StatusEnum.Pending)
              //      val!= null
               //  }
    username unique: true
    password validator : { val , obj ->
                  if (obj.status != StatusEnum.Pending)
                    val != null
               }

    contacts nullable: true
    notifications nullable : true
    username nullable: true
    password nullable: true

  }
}
```

UserController.groovy

```
package com.vproc.member
import com.vproc.common.StatusEnum
import com.vproc.exception.CustomValidationException;


class UserController extends AbstractS2UiController {

  def saltSource
  def userCache
  def springSecurityService
  def mailService
  def messageSource


  def create = {
    //Subscriber user = lookupUserClass().newInstance(params)
    UserCommand command = new UserCommand()
    [command: command, authorityList: sortedRoles()]
  }


  def save = { UserCommand  command ->
    if (command.hasErrors()) {
      render view: 'create', model: [command: command]
      return
    }

    Subscriber user = lookupUserClass().newInstance(params)
    Profile profile = new Profile(emailAddress : command.emailAddress, phoneNumber: "234555", isDefaultProfile: "true").save()
    Party person = new Person(firstName: command.firstName, lastName: command.lastName, profile: profile).save()
    user.party = person

    if(! user.party.hasErrors()){
      if (params.password) {
        String salt = saltSource instanceof NullSaltSource ? null : params.username
        user.password = springSecurityUiService.encodePassword(params.password, salt)
        user.status = StatusEnum.Active
      }else{
        user.status = StatusEnum.Pending
      }
      Subscriber loggedinSubscriber = Subscriber.get( springSecurityService.principal.id )
      user.customer = loggedinSubscriber.customer
      if (!user.save(flush: true)) {
        flash.message = "not able to save user"
      }
    }
    else{
        flash.message = "not able to save user"
      }

    //addRoles(user)
    //flash.message = "User has been added"
    flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), user.id])}"
    redirect( action : "list" )
  }



  def edit = {
    String username
    def user = params.username ? lookupUserClass().findWhere((usernameFieldName): params.username) : null
    if (!user) user = findById()
    if (!user) return
      return buildUserModel(user)
  }

  // def contacts = Contact.findAllBySubscriber( loggedinSubscriber)

  def userSettings = {
    Subscriber loggedinSubscriber = Subscriber.get( springSecurityService.principal.id )
    if (loggedinSubscriber){
    Profile profile = Profile?.get(params.id);
    Party person = profile?.Person?.get(params.id);
    if (!person){
      flash.message = "could not find user with ${params.id}"
      redirect action: list
    }
    else
    [person: person, authorityList: sortedRoles()]
    }
    else {
      redirect(controller: "login" , action:"login");
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to edit profile of currently logged-in user using method `userSettings` in `usercontroller`. I got id of currently logged in user id but I am not able to use that id with profile and person.

```
Subscriber loggedinSubscriber = Subscriber.get( springSecurityService.principal.id )
    if (loggedinSubscriber){
    Profile profile = Profile?.get(params.id);
    Party person = profile?.Person?.get(params.id);
```

Using above code, profile value is null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I dont't want to understand all of your domain modeling, so I'm answering on the thing that I noticed right after having a look at your code. I hope it helps, otherwise just use debug and logging a lot to tackle down your error. And read the documentation.

First of all, in `Profile.groovy` (and other Domains) use a map to define `belongsTo`:

```
static belongsTo = [person:Person]
```

that also does not look right:

```
Profile profile = Profile?.get(params.id);
```

When you have a static access to a grovvy class (upper case first letter) you don't need the questionmark. Is `params.id` supposed to be the ID of the profile? Then you need to use the `findBy` methods:

```
Profile profile = Profile.findById(params.id);
```

Then in the next line you have to use the key from your `belongsTo` map again, so `person` instead of `Person`:

```
// no get or findBy required
Party person = profile?.person
```

Hope it helps

Comment: hi @moeti, I tried with you way but did not get. I think problem with that I got logged-in user id by loggedinSubscriber. But is there any way of using it with profile or person. Second can I use profile or person directly to get logged in user by using type casting?

Comment: It's better to use `get` than `findById` because `get` calls are cached much more intelligently than finder calls which can only use the query cache.

Comment: hi @moeti how to use loggedinSubscriber which is having id of currently logged in user with profile and person. I tried with ur suggestion but profile and person are null.

Comment: hi @BurtBeckwith how to use loggedinSubscriber which is having id of currently logged in user with profile and person. I tried with moeTi's suggestion but profile and person are null. Any idea

Comment: @BurtBeckwith wow thanks, I didn't even know that's possible. learned something new today

Answer (score 0):

I got solution  with following code:

```
  def userSettings = {
    Subscriber loggedinSubscriber = Subscriber.get( springSecurityService.principal.id )
    Party person = Person?.get(loggedinSubscriber.party.id)
    Profile profile = person?.profile
    [userInstance: profile, authorityList: sortedRoles()]
  }
```

Thanks BurtBeckwith and moeTi.